# How does praying towards Kaabah not amount to Shirk?

Tags: salat, belief, shirk, hajj, kaabah

Assalamu alaikum. I am following Islam and very proud to be Muslim. I have few question to clarify my doubts.

1. Islam is against of idol worship and all the activities in Islam is different than the other religions. why we circle the kabba during the hajj or anytime. Hinduism does the same circle the temples.
2. Why we pray facing the kabba which is build of stone.

*Note: The reason of asking this question is to clarify my doubts.*

Answer (score 9):

In the name of Allah

1 .  At first I should say that Tavaf does not mean the worshiping idol. if respecting to something means the idolatry so the ones who respect each other , are the idolater . Moreover this is an order from Allah and thus it has especial philosophy for itself. 
Tavaf (I mean circling the Kaaba ) is for receiving mercy and forgiveness from Allah and is like the rebirth for the human . the angles circle around the empyrean Kaaba and so Muslims should circle around that with their hearths .

> > the prophet ( PBUH ) said :
> >
> > « إِنَّ اللَّهَ یُبَاهِی بِالطَّائِفِینَ »
>
> Allah proud of the ones who circle the Kaaba (1)

Pilgrims should circle the Kaaba with their hearts and because of that Allah align this Kaaba with the empyrean Kaaba  in a line ,so  Muslims circle around that and in fact they worship Allah .

> “Imam Sajjad says: I ask from my father Imam Hussein that why should
>   we circle around the Kaaba for seven times? .  He said:  (when Allah
>   decided to create the human as his successor, the angles said, you
>   want to create the humans who kill each other ?. Allah answered, I
>   know something that you can’t understand) . (Al-Baqara , verse 30 )
>
> thus , Allah deprived them from his mercy for seven thousand years ,
>   then forgave them and because of that in fourth sky built a house and
>   aligned Beit Allah AL haram in a line in front of and seven Tavaf for that
>   and it means that  for  one thousand years , one circle is obligatory 
>    so seven circles became obligatory for the humans like angles . “
>   (2)

In Tavaf you should circle for seven times. The number seven has some secrets like seven skies, seven seas, seven days of the week .

2. Allah in Quran, Surah Al-Baqara , verse 144 , says :

We certainly see you turning your face about in the sky. We will surely turn you to a Qiblah of your liking: so turn your face towards the Masjed al Haram, and wherever you may be, turn your faces towards it! Indeed those who were given the Book surely know that it is the truth from their Lord. And Allah is not oblivious of what they do.

Thus praying toward the Kaaba is an order from Allah. As you know, Allah knows all of languages in the world and his existence is out of time, but we should pray in Arabic language and in an especial period of time. Despite the fact that, Allah is in every place, we should pray in an especial direct. Because of those conditions, Muslims went forward in different aspects of science like geography, mathematics and geometry. The most important reason of this order is the alliance of Muslims with many cultural and educational effects.

(1) . تاریخ بغداد ، ج5 ، ص369 ؛ حلیة الاولیاء ، ج8 ، ص216 ؛ مسند ابی یعلی ، ج4 ، ص330 ، روایت4589 ؛ عوالی اللئالی ، ج1 ، ص96 ، روایت۸

(2) . بحار 11/110 ح 25، علل الشرایع /406/ ح 1 نقل از موسوعه كلمات الحسین علیه السلام /704

Comment: Accurate answer but how do you know that allah has deprived angels from his mercy what versus is there in regards to this plus angels dont have free will main purpose of their creation is to worship allah and obey him they cannot commit sins to be deprived from gods mercy, please let me know how u concluded this and if there is any versus in regards to this?

Answer (score 6):

The fundamental wisdom that can resolve all such questions (i.e. charges of shirk in cases when certain objects are involved in worship) is that **it is in essence impossible to worship Allah without these means and intermediaries.**

But these means and intermediaries are very very diverse, from words, actions and gestures that you use to pray to Allah (chants, hands held in begging, prostration, etc.), to places and formations (mosque, congregations etc.), to symbols and symbolic rituals (Kabba, Hajj, struggle between Safa and Marva, etc.) they are all meant to serve as means by which we seek closeness to and worship Allah. We may even add to this list some of the people, e.g. Prophets and saints as those who manifest Allah's attributes and will and can therefore help us seek closeness to Allah. That is, we can (and indeed do, whether realize or not) worship Allah *through* these close friends of Allah.

The important implication of this fundamental wisdom is that there exists and there can be no direct way of direct communion with Allah. That's just impossible. Even if you try to 'directly' focus on Allah's essence in a vain attempt to supposedly bypass these means, there's still the mediation of your mind and soul and also all the intervening levels of creation between you and Allah, e.g. angels and the Holy Spirit.

The conclusive implication of this for the problem of shirk is that no act of worship to Allah through means amounts to shirk. Shirk is about associating partners with Allah in His Divinity; for example, assuming that Kabba holds some innate Divine powers or that Prophets can do miracles independent of Allah, or that Allah needs any of these intermediaries to sustain itself. But to deny the essential role that all these means play in making worship of Allah possible for us is to simply be unrealistic and irrational. In fact, even Allah Himself in Sura Ma'ida explicitly urges us to seek means of closeness to Him:

> O you who believe! Be conscious of God, and seek the means of approach
>   to Him, and strive in His cause, so that you may succeed.
>   [(5:35)](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.itani/5:35)

This is because that's just how closeness to Allah is achieved. And this is the basic wisdom upon which all allegations of shirk should be examined.

Answer (score 1):

Wa Aleikum Al Salam Wa Rahmat Allah Wa Barakatuh

Islam is against getting attached to any material that leads to worshiping creatures, you are not allowed to seek good luck from a stone or a grave or a wristband cause it leads to worshiping the creatures related to these objects.

Circling around the Kaaba, cuddling the Qur’an, facing Kaaba, believing in the power of Zam Zam water all leads to one thing, getting attached to the owner of these materials and that's Allah Taala.

And that’s why it is not banned but its encouraged.

Comment: Now by the same token, what if I hold a piece of jewel in my chest and respect it for its beauty and be also lead to the majesty of the Creator who has made it so beautiful?

Answer (score 1):

1.) When we circle the Kaaba we are not worshiping *it*, but rather the one who *created it*.

2.) We pray facing it simply because Allah told us to, not to worship it but worship Him. Besides, if we didn't face it, where would we face instead?? It unites us as an Ummah so at prayer times we feel like we are all worshiping the same Deity and that we aren't alone in this religion.

Proof: Al-Bara' b. 'Azib reported: I said prayer with the Apostle (may peace be upon him) turning towards Bait-ul-Maqdis for sixteen months till this verse of Surah Baqara wis revealed:" And wherever you are turn your faces towards it" (ii. 144). This verse was revealed when the Apostle (may peace be upon him) had said prayer. A person amongst his people passed by the people of Ansar as they were engaged in prayer. He narrated to them (this command of Allah) and they turned their faces towards the Ka'ba.

And

Anas reported: The Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) used to pray towards Bait-ul-Maqdis, that it was revealed (to him):" Indeed We see the turning of the face to heaven, wherefore We shall assuredly cause thee to turn towards Qibla which shall please thee. So turn thy face towards the sacred Mosque (Ka'ba)" (ii. 144). A person from Banu Salama was going; (he found the people) in ruk'u (while) praying the dawn prayer and they had said one rak'ah. He said in a loud voice: Listen! The Qibla has been changed and they turned towards (the new) Qibla (Ka'ba) in that very state.

Answer (score 0):

To worship is to praise some being, and to attribute supernatural beauty, purity, wisdom and power to it. In Islam, worship is allowed only towards Allah (there is no god but God). When Muslims circle Ka'ba or pray towards Ka'ba, they do not worship Ka'ba; they follow the command of Allah to do so. Allah wanted Muslim to have a single point of focus and attention when they worship him in the form of salat and hajj. Allah does not occupy space and cannot be described in material terms. Ka'ba is just a revered means and symbol for unification and identification of the Muslim community. "All praise is due to God alone, the Sustainer of all the worlds."

Comment: "To worship is to praise some being and attribute supernatural beauty, etc" is a very inaccurate definition for worship. Angels for example have supernatural attributes and can be praised as such but that doesn't amount to worship.