# Do muslims worship Kaabah

Tags: salat, kaabah, worship

I know it is prohibited in Islam to worship any other than **Allah**.

And it is mentioned in surah Ikhlas (I love these lines) that:

```
Say, "He is Allah , [who is] One,
Allah , the Eternal Refuge.
He neither begets nor is born,
Nor is there to Him any equivalent."
```

[surah Ikhlas reference](http://quran.com/112)

> then why muslims raise their **index finger** towards Kaabah at the time of **Jalsa/Qaidah** (sitting position in Namaj/Salat) by reciting **surah Attahiyat**

Many people here didn't get, what I want to ask:

1. Surah Ikhlas describes who is Allah
2. When we raise our index finger while reciting surah Attahiyat, see [translation](https://islampeace1.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/attahiyat-u-lilahi-wasalawat-u-watayi-batu-the-whole-tashhud-its-meaning/), does not mean that we refer "**Kaabah as Allah**" which
   contradicts Surah Ikhlas ?

Comment: related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16945/how-does-praying-towards-kaabah-not-amount-to-shirk

Comment: @infatuated I want to know why we muslims raise our index finger towards kaabah while we recite surah attahiyat translation is here[link](https://islampeace1.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/attahiyat-u-lilahi-wasalawat-u-watayi-batu-the-whole-tashhud-its-meaning/)

Comment: Did you read the Q&As I linked? In my answer there I explained why pretty much in all acts of worship certain objects are inevitably involved, and why this does not constitute shirk so long as one is already conscious of Monotheism. As for raising index finger, same rule applies. Kabba is only a sign or symbol of Allah that we orient ourselves towards for outward uniformity in our acts of worship among other reasons! So just as praying towards a stone structure five times a day does not mean that we worship the stone structure, so does raising our fingers or hands towards it!

Comment: Attahiyat is no surah is it's not even related to the quran it's a du'a which our Messenger (peace be upon him) has taught us!

Answer (score 2):

Muslims **do not** worship Kabba. Muslims worship Allah *in the direction of* or *towards* Kabba.

We not only raise index finger in direction of Kabba, but also stand in direction Kabba, in fact all Salat is in direction of Kabba.

If there is a building, chair, table, or any plant etc, in front of you while you are praying, it does not mean that you are worshipping it, unless you do it intentionally for worshipping it. In fact, everything you do depends on your intention(niyat). So if your intention is to worship Allah, then you're worshipping Allah. But make sure there is no idol like thing, which has face, in front of you.

And for your information, muslims do not raise their index finger while reciting *Ataiyhat* or *Tashahud*, but after reciting Tashahud, while reciting Kalma Shahadat/second Kalma.

Answer (score -1):

In reality it is not a correct sentence to declare that are worshipping Kaabah. because the very important point that you must pay attention to, is that people or in fact muslims who are vending around the kaabah, they are vending around it with the intention of Allah. In other word I must say that muslims look at this as a symbol of allah not as an idel. Because there must be a symbol for muslims to be gathered altogather in a specific place. Therefore it is not true if some people endeavor to accuse the muslims to worshipping kabbah for itself not with the intention of allah.